# log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: log.txt (Permission denied)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, logging

Dynamic web project in eclipse with spring mvc, use log4j-1.2.15.jar to create          the log file, but I get the error that I mentioned in the title. 
I also made a java project in eclipse using non-web library log4j-1.2.16.jar,        the first  time he gave me the permission error after denid instead I created the log file

```
log4j.properties

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.File=log.txt
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n


package Log;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class LoggingTrial
{
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggingTrial.class);
    private static double cambio;
    private static double euro;
    private static double dollars;
    private static boolean sw;

    public static void logging()
    {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
        {
            logger.debug("main(String[]) - Avvio");
        }


        sw = false;

        logger.info("Tasso di conversione: " );

        while (!sw)
        {
            logger.info("Valore in dollari: " );

            sw = true;
        }

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
        {
            logger.debug("main(String[]) - Fine");
        }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your app cannot write to 'logs' folder. Not related to log4j configuration as such.
Create the folder if it doesn't exist and give it enough permissions for the web app to write into it.

Comment: Where should I create the folder. with ubuntu I have a problem with the terminal can also set the permission from the GUI I've seen that I can do it.

Comment: put your properties file path in the cmd line this way :

-Dlog4j.configuration=<FILE_PATH>  (ex: log4j.properties)

Comment: I resolved I wrote in the file. Properties of different instructions that I found in an article that said how to integrate log4j with spring mvc.

Comment: I do not know if it would work the same with the previous instructions of the file. Better properties by specifying the path to the folder that contains the log